# C# WPF Windows needs to click before it focus

Tags: c#, wpf, window

i've searched a lot of articles here but failed to search for the answers.

i have a window which i want to focus on the text box on the load. But the thing is its not working properly. Its like you have to click on the form first before i gets focus.

And this only happens when there is an user control loaded first before that window does. (like user control for continue payment).

```
this.Activate();
this.Focus();
```

doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Angelo adds XAML code and you want to set focus on the textbox on window load?

Comment: it loses all the focus on the window. Even the keydown doesnt work anymore

Comment: add code XAML and C# both

Comment: I know i should put codes there, and how about you help me out what to put there lol

Comment: Can you post your xaml and c# codes?

Comment: @AngeloSanchez Use the **edit** button under your question to update it to add code.

Answer (score 0):

put it on the onload event.

this.textboxName.Focus();